# Yield from coroutine vs yield from task

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio

Guido van Rossum, in his speech in 2014 on Tulip/Asyncio [shows the slide](http://youtu.be/aurOB4qYuFM?t=53m8s):

> **Tasks vs coroutines**
>
> - Compare:
>
>   - res = yield from  some_coroutine(...)
>   - res = yield from Task(some_coroutine(...))
> - Task can make progress without waiting for it
>
>   - As log as you wait for something else
>
>     - i.e. yield from

And I'm completely missing the point.

From my point of view both constructs are identical:

In case of bare coroutine - It gets scheduled, so the task is created anyways, because scheduler operates with Tasks, then coroutine caller coroutine is suspended until callee is done and then becomes free to continue execution.

In case of `Task` - All the same - new task is schduled and caller coroutine waits for its completion.

What is the difference in the way that code executed in both cases and what impact it has that developer should consider in practice?

p.s.
Links to authoritative sources (GvR, PEPs, docs, core devs notes) will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For the calling side co-routine `yield from coroutine()` feels like a function call (i.e. it will again gain control when coroutine() finishes).

`yield from Task(coroutine())` on the other hand feels more like creating a new thread. `Task()` returns almost instantly and very likely the caller gains control back before the `coroutine()` finishes.

The difference between `f()` and `th = threading.Thread(target=f, args=()); th.start(); th.join()` is obvious, right?

Comment: So the difference is in how execution will be scheduled by the scheduler? Bare coroutine gets higher "priority" and task gets lower?

Comment: There are no priorities in asyncio at all.
For bare coroutine you have to use `yield from coro()` for coroutine running, in case of task construction like `async(coro())` will execute coroutine in parallel with others.

Comment: You mean that there will be no context switch in case of bare coroutine?

Comment: There is (or, correctly, a coroutine may cause context switch and usually does) but you have to explicitly execute it and wait for finishing via `yield from`.
For tasks you have to start task only (`asyncio.async(coro())`) and free to wait until task finished via `yield from` or just go ahead and do something else -- the task will continue own run.
Say again, the difference is like diff between function calls and creating new OS thread.

Comment: I understood you like that there is no difference `yield from some_coro()` and `yield from Task(some_coro())` - correct? Notice that GvR was shown exactly that on his slide - and he was talked like there IS some difference.

Comment: From **final result** perspective there is **no difference**, yes.

Task case is a bit slower though.

There **is** difference in **how** code is executed in both cases.

Comment: So what is the difference? `yield from Task(some_coro(...))` will be executed in the background and `yield form some_coro()` will be executed... how?

Comment: In current execution context, obviously.
If coroutine was executed by `loop.run_until_complete(coro())` the context is foreground. You can also call `yield from` from task.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is the "foreground" and what is the "foreground"? Context switch happens in both cases, so both cases can be compared with starting a new thread, because the are both asynchronous. So its sounds like "foreground" is asynchronous execution with higher priority and "background" with lower.

Comment: Oooh. All contexts have the same priority. Period.
As main thread in python program has the same priority as other threads created by user.

Comment: I'm not stating that priorities are exists, I'm asking for some details about what is "background" and what "foreground" here.

Comment: Is this statement correct: if you do `yield from bare_coro()` - `bare_coro` will be executed right next of the caller coroutine, with no chance to other coroutines executed before it? Some code: https://gist.github.com/AndrewPashkin/844d17f2ab4f4c88be42

Comment: Yes, you are right.
Technically `yield from coro()` executes coroutine immediately, `async(coro())` schedules execution by `loop.call_soon()` call.

Comment: Is it implementation detail, or it is in specs? I cant find anything in `asyncio` docs about that. Maybe it is implicit spec, hence `yield from bare_coro()` is just a synchronous Python code actually, and when Scheduler calls `next()` on caller coroutine - `bare_coroutine()` invoked synchronously as regular code with no `asyncio` magic?

Comment: Very interesting by the way, that python 2.7 backport - `trollius` works completely different with [the same code](https://gist.github.com/AndrewPashkin/844d17f2ab4f4c88be42)

Comment: Well, it is implementation details . Trollius doesn't use `yield from` and not fully compatible with asyncio.

Comment: Custom event loops that fully compatible with asyncio utilizes `yield from` and reuses asyncio.Task which calls `loop.call_soon()`. Non 100% compatible systems may invite own contracts and have own implementation details.

Comment: What if consider alternative Python implementations, like PyPy? If they will implement 3.4 and will strictly follow official specs, should they reproduce that "sycnrhonous execution" feature?

Comment: Yes, if PyPy will support 3.4 (only 3.2 for now AFAIK) it will work with coroutines in the same way as CPython 3.4 does. At least I think so but cannot guarantee. I'm CPython Core developer, not PyPy one.

Comment: What I mean is that does Python _language specification_ asserts that `yield from bare_coro()` **must** work like that in any implementation?

Comment: Yes, PEP 380 explicitly states this.

Comment: That was it. Now i'm enlightened, thank you! I think you should update the answer with this info.

Answer (score 17):

The point of using `asyncio.Task(coro())` is for cases where you *don't* want to explicitly wait for `coro`, but you want `coro` to be executed in the background while you wait for other tasks. That is what Guido's slide means by

> [A] `Task` can make progress without waiting for it...**as long as you wait
>   for something else**

Consider this example:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def test1():
    print("in test1")


@asyncio.coroutine
def dummy():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("dummy ran")


@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    test1()
    yield from dummy()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
dummy ran
```

As you can see, `test1` was never actually executed, because we didn't explicitly call `yield from` on it.

Now, if we use `asyncio.async` to wrap a `Task` instance around `test1`, the result is different:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def test1():
    print("in test1")


@asyncio.coroutine
def dummy():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("dummy ran")


@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    asyncio.async(test1())
    yield from dummy()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
in test1
dummy ran
```

So, there's really no practical reason for using `yield from asyncio.async(coro())`, since it's slower than `yield from coro()` without any benefit; it introduces the overhead of adding `coro` to the internal `asyncio` scheduler, but that's not needed, since using `yield from` guarantees that `coro` is going to execute, anyway. If you just want to call a coroutine and wait for it to finish, just `yield from` the coroutine directly.

**Side note:**

I'm using `asyncio.async`* instead of `Task` directly [because the docs recommend it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task):

> Don’t directly create `Task` instances: use the `async()` function or
>   the `BaseEventLoop.create_task()` method.

* Note that as of Python 3.4.4, `asyncio.async` is deprecated in favor of [`asyncio.ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future).

Answer (score 3):

As described in PEP 380, the accepted PEP document that introduced yield from, the expression `res = yield from f()` comes from the idea of the following loop:

```
for res in f():
    yield res
```

With this, things become very clear: if `f()` is `some_coroutine()`, then the coroutine is executed. On the other hand, if `f()` is `Task(some_coroutine())`, `Task.__init__` is executed instead. `some_coroutine()` is not executed, only the newly created generator is passed as the first argument to `Task.__init__`.

Conclusion:

- `res = yield from some_coroutine()` => coroutine continues execution and returns the next value
- `res = yield from Task(some_coroutine())` => a new task is created, which stores a non-executed `some_coroutine()` generator object.