# Retrieving data from python's coroutine object

Tags: python, python-3.7, coroutine, whois, python-asyncio

I am trying to learn async, and now I am trying to get whois information for a batch of domains. I found this lib [aiowhois](https://pypi.org/project/aiowhois/), but there are only a few strokes of information, not enough for such newbie as I am.

This code works without errors, but I don't know how to print data from parsed `whois` variable, which is coroutine object.

```
resolv = aiowhois.Whois(timeout=10)

async def coro(url, sem):
    parsed_whois = await resolv.query(url)

async def main():
    tasks = []
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(4)

    for url in domains:
        task = asyncio.Task(coro(url, sem))
        tasks.append(task)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: I think you can avoid using tasks. Just apply `gather` to `coro(url, sem)` directly. You can rename the list of tasks to `coros` if you like

Comment: What do you use the semaphore for?

Comment: This code made from parts of other programs, i'm still not very clear about everything here =(

Comment: Not answering your question but just helping for the future: especially in gTLDs, whois is dying, the new protocol to use is RDAP. Since it is based on HTTPS, any HTTP async library will be able to handle it without problems. Except with very good reasons, new software should be built using RDAP today not whois anymore. Also in both cases the input should be a domain name, not an URL.

Comment: This information is very useful for me!! I didn't know that, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid using tasks. Just apply gather to the coroutine directly.
In case you are confused about the difference, this [SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753401/difference-between-coroutine-and-future-task-in-python-3-5) might help you (especially the second answer).

You can have each coroutine return its result, without resorting to global variables:

```
async def coro(url):
    return await resolv.query(url)

async def main():
    domains = ...
    ops = [coro(url) for url in domains]
    rets = await asyncio.gather(*ops)
    print(rets)
```

Please see the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) to learn more about how to use `gather` or `wait` or even more options

Note: if you are using the latest python versions, you can also simplify the loop running with just

```
asyncio.run(main())
```

Note 2: I have removed the semaphore from my code, as it's unclear why you need it and where.

Comment: I see what you mean, will try to modify my code. Thank you for your response

Comment: As SO etiquette, if my contribution helped you, please show your appreciation by upvoting it and/or accepting it as the best answer. Many thanks

Comment: I'm not enough 4 reputation to make votes at the moment (11 only need 15). But i will when i got them. Thanks

Comment: you never did and it's been almost a year :o

Comment: honey bees don't live a year :(

Answer (score 3):

```
all_parsed_whois = []  # make a global

async def coro(url, sem):
    all_parsed_whois.append(await resolv.query(url))
```

If you want the data as soon as it is available you could task.add_done_callback()

[python asyncio add_done_callback with async def](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345139/python-asyncio-add-done-callback-with-async-def)