# The execution order inside a corutine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

[Yield from coroutine vs yield from task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076577/yield-from-coroutine-vs-yield-from-task)
In this link, there is an example give by @dano that:

```py
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def test1():
    print("in test1")


@asyncio.coroutine
def dummy():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("dummy ran")


@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    test1()
    yield from dummy()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The output is only

```
dummy ran
```

I can't add comment to that directly, so I have to ask a new question here;
**(1) why the test1() isn't executed in order** in such corutine function. 
Whether corutine can only use the following two ways?

```
yield from cor()
asyncio.async(cor())
```

Where did test1() go?

**(2) There is also some other problems in understanding the differnence of the followng two methods to use corutine() function. Are they the same?**

```py
yield from asyncio.async(cor())
asyncio.async(cor())
```

I use the following code to explain:

```py
import random
import datetime
global a,b,c
import asyncio

a = [random.randint(0, 1<<256) for i in range(500000)]  
b= list(a)
c= list(a)


@asyncio.coroutine
def test1():
    global b
    b.sort(reverse=True)
    print("in test1")


@asyncio.coroutine
def test2():
    global c
    c.sort(reverse=True)
    print("in test2")


@asyncio.coroutine
def dummy():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("dummy ran")

@asyncio.coroutine
def test_cor():
    for i in asyncio.sleep(1):
        yield i

@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    test1()
    print("hhhh_______________________")
    asyncio.async(test1())
    asyncio.async(test2())
    print("hhhh_______________________")
    print("hhh")

    asyncio.async(dummy())
    yield from test_cor()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
print("hhhhhhh")
```

However the output is

```
hhhh_______________________
hhhh_______________________
hhh
in test1
in test2
hhhhhhh
```

It even didn't execute the `dummy()` function !

And I use

```py
@asyncio.coroutine
def test2():
    # global c
    # c.sort(reverse=True)
    print("in test2")
```

**(3) without sorting and I think test2 should run faster so that test1 is output after test2. However, the output didn't change. I don't know why.**

**(4)And I also tried to remove sorting for both test1() and test2(), then amazingly, dummy() runs and output the following. Why ??**

```
hhhh_______________________
hhhh_______________________
hhh
in test1
in test2
dummy ran
hhhhhhh
```

I don't know how these things happens....I am relly bewilerded.

Comment: You need to use ` yield from`.

Comment: Does ```yield from test1()``` and  ```asyncio.async(test1()) ```  the same ?

Comment: What's the executing order of  ``` print("hhh");  yield from cor();```  It will ```print``` first right ? So why do we usually use corutine function since the normally they exectued in order.

Comment: Calling a coroutine doesn't execute it. You need to await it (`yield from` in the case of 3.4 syntax).

Comment: So ```yield from task``` will suspend it and open a new thread for it right? So the task can be run in parallel

Comment: asyncio doesn't use threads and tasks don't execute in parallel.

Comment: But the link I mentioned in another link said so.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076577/yield-from-coroutine-vs-yield-from-task

Comment: I see some comparisons to using threads, but there's no mention of asyncio using threads.

Comment: So is there any parallism inside?

Comment: No. asyncio uses cooperative multitasking. Only one task can execute at a time. A task can be suspended to allow another to execute while it is waiting (eg, for a response from a network call).

Comment: I update my question above. So the coruntine will be executed anyway right? But in my undated question, I run the code and asyncio.async(dummy()) doesn't even run.

Comment: `test1` does nothing to yield execution to `test2` so the latter won't start running until the former completes. And I believe you need to consume `test_cor` as a generator if you want it to yield execution back to `dummy` (or remove the `yield` so it can execute normally).

Comment: What's the meaning of consume `test_cor` as a generator ? I use `yield from test_cor()` and I think it's a way of using `test_cor()` as a generator.....(Also, why not add an answer to this question directly :) It will be easier to be accepted...

Comment: In the body of `test_cor` you use `yield`. Generators don't begin execution until you consume them.  Replace `test_cor`'s entire body with `yield from asyncio.sleep(1)` and then you should see `dummy` execute.

Comment: I still didn't see dummy.....I have replaced the whole body.

Comment: If I use `yield from asyncio.async(dummy())` I can see dummy execute. But I can use `yield from asyncio.async(dummy())` to see dummy execute even I don't replace the whole body....

Comment: Is there any difference between `yield from asyncio.async(dummy())` and `yield from dummy()` ?

Comment: With the `yield from`, no. Without it, yes. Without it `main` completes before `dummy` finishes and the loop is suspended. With it, `main` is blocked until `dummy` completed.